# AWS EC2 Performance for Global

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, elastic-load-balancer

My project uses a Node Client and a backend API Server both of which are deployed in Singapore region.

What is best strategy to optimize the performance to serve users in for example, North America?

I've heard of cloudfront which is mainly useful for static contents. But my site calls API from backend server and serves dynamic content.

Comment: *"I've heard of cloudfront which is mainly useful for static contents."*  That's not exactly right.  CloudFront also optimizes the Internet transport and TLS negotiation time for dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the static content in S3 and serve using CloudFront that will remove the load on the server for the static content completely.

If you have a considerable number of users from North America, deploy the application in US-EAST-1 region and use route53 [latency based](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-latency) routing and it will make sure requests from North America goes to the application deployed in US-EAST-1 so they will get a response with low latency.

Comment: does this route53 latency based routing also work if i have a load balancer?